# Как заменить конструкцию query_posts на get_posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте **wordpress** есть конструкция с `query_posts`

```
query_posts( array( 'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE, 'meta_query' => array( array('key' => 'cp_category', 'value' => 'Не определено', 'compare' => '=')), 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 ) );
get_template_part( 'loop', 'ad_listing' ); 
wp_reset_query();
```

На первой странице все выводится хорошо, но пагинация уже не работает. Пытаюсь переписать с заменой на `get_posts` вот так, но выводится в мета-данных какая-то полупустая чушь.

```
$categories = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE, 'meta_query' => array( array('key' => 'cp_category', 'value' => 'Не определено', 'compare' => '=')), 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 ) );
foreach( $categories as $$category ) {
get_template_part( 'loop', 'ad_listing' ); 
}
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
```

Как это исправить и решить проблему с пагинацией?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пагинация заработает при выполнении такого условия:

> For getting the current pagination number on a static front page (Page
>   template) you have to use the 'page' query variable:
>   [Ссылка на источник](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
        $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;   
    } else {
        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Для пагинации нужен параметр `paged` и количество постов на странице(по умолчанию берется с настроек WordPress, но можно указать свое)

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
    'post_type' => APP_POST_TYPE,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'cp_category', 
            'value' => 'Не определено', 
            'compare' => '='
    ), 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
);
$categories = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    get_template_part( 'loop', 'ad_listing' );
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: сорри, но плюсануть не могу,т.к. выводит список точно такой же чуши, как и при моем варианте

Comment: `paged` возвращает равным 1